# java.lang.NullPointerException with existing and correct file path

Tags: java, audio, nullpointerexception, clip

I don't understand why I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.SoftMidiAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Even though the same code works in my another application. The file path is correct, the file is there. I'm clueless.

Relevant code before sound method:

```
String soundpath = "res/sound.au";
sound(soundpath);
```

Here's my sound method:

```
public static void sound(String path){
try {

AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SoundTest.class.getResource(path));
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audio);
clip.start();

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Might wanna check: " + path + "\n");
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this with several different WAV-formats and most recently with using .AU soundfile and always getting the same error.

Comment: The file is located at [project folder]/src/res

Comment: The file needs to be on your `CLASSPATH`. Is the `CLASSPATH` set appropriately in both applications?

Comment: Did you forget to stop the clip?

Comment: @RobinGreen Thank you. That was it. The other application didn't have a defined package, so the classpath was different. The simplest things... You can set that as your answer and I'll green it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file needs to be on your `CLASSPATH`. Is the `CLASSPATH` set appropriately in both applications?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you try to create an AudioInputStream from a null URL.